What is the meaning of "infinity" in the Continuum Hypothesis
Quoting from this article How the continuum hypothesis could have been a
fundamental axiom by Joel David Hamkins:

The continuum hypothesis (CH) is the assertion that the cardinality of
the set of real numbers is the first uncountable infinity, or in other
words, that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$.

How is the word “infinity” defined here?

Presumably he means "infinite cardinal."

The entire phrase "the first uncountable infinity" refers to the aleph number $\aleph_1$.

An infinite set will be defined as a set which is not finite, or a set where there exists an injection to a proper subset of itself. The second notion is called dedekind-infinite.

@CyclotomicField Thanks for the comment. But I'm looking for a mathematical definition of "infinity". (Preferably independent of the set theory) Is there such a definition? A definition that conforms to mathematical definition as described in this page https://abstractmath.org/MM/MMDefs.htm#definitionsinmath will be nice. Is there such a definition?

@zeynel the most common definition of infinite is not finite. I prefer the dedekind-infinite definition since it doesn't beg the question as to what finite is. Cantor's set theory is the foundation of modern mathematics in no small part to the fact that it allows us to accurately describe infinity. So you'll want to keep it. In real analysis it's common to add two tokens called $\infty$ and $-\infty$ to discuss the behavior of certain unbounded functions or sequences. Sometimes you'll see a single token called $\infty$ which can have geometric significance such as with the Riemann sphere.

@CyclotomicField "...infinite is not finite." I'm puzzled by this "definition". "Infinite" already means "not finite." We are merely replacing the negation prefix "in" with negation word "not". This is like defining "unbound" as "not bound" which is not a definition but a play on words. So, to me "infinite is not finite" cannot be a definition of infinite. And as you say, this begs the question about what finite is.

@zeynel yeah that's why I prefer the dedekind-infinite definition. Then finite is simply not infinite but we have a clear description of what infinite entails. Note that negations are commonly used for definitions such as a composite number being defined as a number that is not prime. So there is nothing particularly strange about defining something this way.

@CyclotomicField (and zeynel) There's nothing circular about it. We start by defining "finite" as "In bijection with an ordinal which is less than every nonzero limit ordinal," and then "infinite" is just the negation of that. Alternately, if you want a "structural" definition of finiteness you can use "can be linearly ordered and every linear order is a well-order," which is optimal in a precise sense.

@NoahSchweber I don’t understand your definition of "finite”. You have a well-ordered set. Well-ordered means that the set has a clear beginning. “In bijection” with what? I don’t understand. Maybe you want to say that a finite set is set with a beginning and end. Can you elaborate further?

@NoahSchweber And also since a set is defined as an unordered collection how come a set can be "well-ordered"? I'm puzzled about this.
